# text flowing out of div

Tags: css, border

When the text is **without spaces**  and **more than the div size 200px** it's flowing out 
The width is defined as 200px
I have put my code here http://jsfiddle.net/madhu131313/UJ6zG/
You can see the below pictures 
**edited**: I want the the text to go to the next line

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 264, accepted):

It's due to the fact that you have one long word without spaces. You can use the `word-wrap` property to cause the text to break:

```
#w74 { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

It has fairly good browser support, too. [See documentation about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap).

Comment: it didn't work for me [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) is another example.

Comment: word-break: break-all 

This save me

Comment: This one does not work for email templates. Instead you should use  word-break:break-all .

Answer (score 147):

Use

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

It will prevent text from flowing out of the `div`. It will break the text as it reaches the end of the `div`.

Answer (score 40):

You should use `overflow:hidden;`  or `scroll`

http://jsfiddle.net/UJ6zG/1/

or with php you could short the long words...

Comment: Awesome.sorry to mention I want it to go to the next line like gmail chat or facebook chat :)

Comment: Then you can use @chipcullen 's version with word-wrap!  demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UJ6zG/3/

Answer (score 19):

You need to apply the following CSS property to the container block (div):

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

According to the specifications (source [CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)):

> The `overflow-wrap` CSS property specifies whether or not the browser should insert line breaks within words to prevent text from overflowing its content box.

With the value set to `break-word`

> To prevent overflow, normally unbreakable words may be broken at arbitrary points if there are no otherwise acceptable break points in the line.

Worth mentioning...

> The property was originally a nonstandard and unprefixed Microsoft extension called `word-wrap`, and was implemented by most browsers with the same name. It has since been renamed to `overflow-wrap`, with `word-wrap` being an alias.

---

If you care about legacy browsers support it's worth specifying both:

```
word-wrap    : break-word;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

Ex. **IE9** does not recognize `overflow-wrap` but works fine with `word-wrap`

Answer (score 15):

This did the trick for me:

`{word-break: break-all; }`

Comment: thank you so much this was the only thing that worked for my (using styled-components in React)

Comment: yes this worked for me as the word will continue to the next line

Comment: Dude I looked at so many suggestions, this worked for me , thanks a lot , you're a live saver!

Comment: it was only thing that worked for text without space!!! much thanks!

Answer (score 13):

this trick works for me:

```css
{
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

[white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) 
[word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

Answer (score 7):

use `overflow:auto` it will give a scroller to your text within the `div` :).

Answer (score 7):

If this helps. Add the following property with value to your selector:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Answer (score 2):

i recently encountered this. I used: `display:block;`

Comment: The only one working for me trying to show a really big text without any spaces in it!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue with `Tailwind`, you could use this as well

```
<p class="break-words ...">...</p>
```

You could read more here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/word-break

Answer (score 0):

This combination just worked for me.  `<asp:Label ID="User" style="white-space:pre-line; word-wrap: break-word" Text="" runat="server" />` in ASP.Net.

Answer (score -5):

If it is just one instance that needs to be wrapped over 2 or 3 lines I would just use a few `<wbr>` in the string. It will treat those just like `<br>` but it wont insert the line break if it isn't necessary.

```
<div id="w74" class="dpinfo">
adsfadsadsads<wbr>fadsadsadsfadsadsa<wbr>dsfadsadsadsfadsadsads<wbr>fadsadsadsfadsadsadsfa<wbr>dsadsadsfadsadsadsfadsad<wbr>sadsfadsadsads<wbr>fadsadsadsfadsads adsfadsads
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/gaby_de_wilde/UJ6zG/37/