# Align or break work that is appearing out of the panel/div

Tags: html, css

Below is the screenshot of my div in which I'm printing the name of the employee.But if the name is too long it exceeds the div.
itried by adding `overflow:auto` which creates a scroll at the bottom of the div that dosen't look good.
Is there any other solution?[image]

Comment: Please post your code - it's very difficult to find the problem if we can only look at an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196885/text-flowing-out-of-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding these:

```
 white-space: nowrap;
 width: <set your width>;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

To clip your text if it is too long or exceeding the set width. Also adds `...` if it exceeds.

Comment: Don't forget applying the `overflow: hidden`. It is already applied in his code. I just add what is necessary. Refer to these link to learn more: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp