# How to put these labels inside a div border?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var val_tujuan = "test";
$('#d_tujuan').on('click', function(){
   var txt_tujuan = "<label class='label label-primary lbl_txt' style='margin:1px;'>"+val_tujuan+"</label>";
   
   $('#d_tujuan').append(txt_tujuan);
      });
```

```css
.lbl_txt{
background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id='fdaftar' class="form-group">
                        <label>Daftar Tujuan</label>
                        <div id='d_tujuan' style="border:#000 1px; background-color:#DDD; min-height:100px;  word-wrap: break-word;">
                        </div>
     </div>
                    </div>
```

I have a script that add labels to a div. But, the problem is the labels pass through the div border? How to fix it? I've tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196885/text-flowing-out-of-div) but nothing works for me. (or maybe I fail to implementing the solutions there)

My jQuery:

```
$('#sel_tujuan').on('change', function(){
        var val_tujuan = $(this).val();
        var txt_tujuan = "<label class='label label-primary lbl_txt' style='margin:1px;'>"+val_tujuan+"</label>";

        $('#d_tujuan').append(txt_tujuan);          
});
```

My Div:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div id='fdaftar' class="form-group">
   <label>Daftar Tujuan</label>
   <div id='d_tujuan' style="border:#000 1px; background-color:#DDD; min-height:100px;word-wrap: break-word"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: pls provide working snippet code.

Comment: sorry, my office internet connection is restricted to certain website only.

Comment: You can create the snippet in your post. Anyway, we need the CSS for the labels.

Comment: I use standart bootstrap css for the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this and give this css  `word-wrap: break-word;` to `d_tujuan` id. Add this css for label.

```
.label.lbl_txt {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```js
var val_tujuan = "test";
$('#d_tujuan').on('click', function(){
  var txt_tujuan = "<label class='label label-primary lbl_txt' style='margin:1px;'>"+val_tujuan+"</label>";

  $('#d_tujuan').append(txt_tujuan);
});
```

```css
.lbl_txt{
background-color:green;
}
.label.lbl_txt {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div id='fdaftar' class="form-group">
      <label>Daftar Tujuan</label>
      <div id='d_tujuan' style="border:#000 1px; background-color:#DDD; min-height:100px; display:block; word-wrap: break-word;">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've add word wrap in my div. but, it still pass the border. pls check my snippet

Comment: it seems to have aconflict with the boostrap css `label label-primary`. I remove this class and it's working. But, i can't remove it due to client request. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was it was not triggered in this way `$('#sel_tujuan').on('change', function()` because there was no such element with id #sej_tujuan so i just put to check its work on click on div.Click div its working. Also there was no such value in div you was trying to get value of div. If you trying to get text of div just use `$('div selected').text();`

```
$('#sel_tujuan').on('change', function(){
        var val_tujuan = $(this).val();
```

like this way no just get value from input, options as far i know maybe you can get value of div probably but this way.

**If you trying to get text of div just use `$('div selected').text();`**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#d_tujuan').click(function(){
        var val_tujuan = $('input').val();
        var txt_tujuan = "<label class='lbl_txt' style='margin:1px;'>"+val_tujuan+"</label>";
        $('#d_tujuan').append(txt_tujuan);          
});
});
```

```css
#d_tujuan {
  border:#000 1px; 
  background-color:#DDD; 
  min-height:100px; 
  display:block;   
  word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div id='fdaftar' class="form-group">
   <label>Daftar Tujuan</label>
   <div id='d_tujuan'></div>
</div>
</div>
<input value='valued'>
```

**Update**

In your Div css   `word-wrap: break-word;` will make your text inside div fit in div

Comment: the text pass the div border

Comment: you want it inside?

Comment: @Vahn Its easy check now i put css in your div

Comment: @Vahn does this help you? If yes check this as asnwered

Comment: I've added the word-wrap inmy div but it still pass the border

Comment: I've add word wrap in my div. but, it still pass the border. pls check my snippet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156309/discussion-between-munkhdelger-tumenbayar-and-vahn).

Comment: it seems to have aconflict with the boostrap css `label label-primary`. I remove this class and it's working. But, i can't remove it due to client request. Any solution?

Comment: sorry, I can't open discussion chat. the office net blocking it

Comment: Vahn just in your css put label label-primary then override its attributes thats all