# Text Flowing Outside div

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to achieve a masonary layout using CSS grid and I am quite there but why is my text not fitting inside the div I tried `word-wrap: break-word;` by referring to [text-flowing-out-of-div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196885/text-flowing-out-of-div) but no success.

Here is the js bin link https://jsbin.com/qufunihaku/edit?output

Please Help !!

Comment: Does it help to add some padding to your inner `div`s: `.parent div {padding: 20px;}`?

Answer (score 0):

If you add some padding in your child-divs like in your work-div, the text fits to the inside of the div:

```
.work{
  grid-area: work;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

As an alternative you could decreace the border-radius size too.